# Export content in features using UUID features

Tags: 7, entities, features

I read the UUID feature description and it says it is used to export content in feature. I installed the module but did not know how to export the content.

Answer (score 6):

The [uuid](http://drupal.org/project/uuid) module has been reworked, and, as of 2012.05.25, [uuid_features](http://drupal.org/project/uuid_features) has not been updated to address those changes (though there is [a patch RTBC](http://drupal.org/node/1245582)).

In the meantime, to export nodes using uuid_features in Drupal 7:

- Install [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) version 7.x-1.0-rc2.
- Install [uuid](http://drupal.org/project/uuid) **version 7.x-1.0-alpha1**. *(Not the latest version.)*
- Install [uuid_features](http://drupal.org/project/uuid_features) version 7.x-1.0-alpha1.
- Enable the `features` module, the `uuid` module, the `uuid_node` module, and the `uuid_features` module
- Go to Configuration > System > Universally unique identifiers, and click the "Create missing UUIDs" button
- Go to Structure > Features > Create feature, and from the "Edit components" dropdown, select "Content: uuid_node", then pick the nodes you'd like to export into your Feature

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful!!I have spent a lot of time trying to find what was wrong in my drupal installation and know it's working fine!Thanks

Comment: Do you know if there are working to integrate the uuid_features with the newer uuid version?

Comment: It looks like on http://drupal.org/node/1245582#comment-6226436, Rob Loach committed the change to the 7.x-1.x branch of UUID Features, so the latest 7.x-1.x-dev version should work with the current UUID module.  (I haven't tried it though.)

Comment: It seems uuid_node isnt required anymore, it was probably merged into one of the above modules

Comment: This answer could be updated and expanded, as it only addresses nodes and ignores entitie bundles such as fielded taxonomy terms.  The UUID features interface has also changed a bit, and there's a configuration step missing (Features > Configure UUID Export tab).  That's the step where you can select entity bundles for export in features.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using [defaultcontent module](http://drupal.org/project/defaultcontent)

Comment: But it does not use the uuid. It forces you to have a machine name for all nodes.

Comment: This has been deprecated