# Features are sweet but what about content?

Tags: nodes, features

I used features successfully to restore my VIEW and content type...but the data for the content type didn't make it? Did I miss the option or is this something you typically bring over manually?

Comment: Features does not do it on their own, you need to install UUID (to make IDs "migrate-able") and UUID_features (for the actual work). But what you do may be wrong. Usually you want code and config to go dev → live, and content to go live → dev, so think twice before you'll embed content in feature.

Answer (score -1):

Features are useful to export (and import) configurations, but is not useful for "entities": users, nodes, files, terms, and so on.

A great module to export and import is [Node Export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export)

Comment: False, [features can be useful with content](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/20498/16495)

Comment: Yes, it works, but I think that this is the "right" way to export nodes. Feature go in "override" state if you edit the node? Features has been created for configurations, I'm not suggest to use it for nodes, simply.

Comment: Sometimes nodes are more a configuration than content. That's designed use case of UUID Features module. In cases like that "override mode" is exactly what should happen.

Comment: You can use nodes for many things, I'm simply saying that nodes should be used as nodes and it's a better developing practice to use other "tools" instead of nodes for configurations.

Comment: Especially for manual pages that are supposed to go with your feature? Why can't they be nodes?.. Of course you are free to have your opinion, but this site aims to be as opinion-less as possible.

Comment: On Drupal there many, many ways to obtain the same thing. Every suggestion is an opinion.. If Features works for you for this "task", it's a good thing, maybe in the future I'll use it in the same way.

Comment: It's not about how I use them; simply your answer does not cover what OP is asking. I wouldn't comment if your suggestion would be in the scope of OPs problem; suggesting that OP should change his planned workflow, when it's based only on your opinion, seems to be a bit too much - especially when his original idea may work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the input...I shall look into both solutions but I like the idea of less is more so if i can use features thats abonus